# How to get autocomplete for local NodeJS modules/packages? [PhpStorm / VS Code]

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, phpstorm, webstorm

I'm learning node and everything around it. I want to create some example projects to learn it step by step. But it's a little bit confusing to understand how it works the right way.

**The Problem**:

I have two projects (packages). The first project is only a module which I want to install locally to the second main project, which is the webapp project.

Both projects have the same core dependencies.

```
// package.json (snippet)
[...]
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
  "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
  "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
  "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.2.1",
  "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
  "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
  "webpack": "^4.1.1",
  "webpack-cli": "^2.0.12"
},
[...]
```

The only difference is that the Webapp Project needs my custom module.

```
// Webapp package.json (snippet)
[...]
"devDependencies": {
  [...]
  "components" : ""file:../components"
} 
[...]
```

**My main module files**

What I want is to get an autocomplete list of the exported 'components' module which I include in my webapp file.

**Components Module:**

```
// --- Components Module - entry.js (will transpile via babel to index.js)

// collect all ES6 Classes
import Component from 'core/Component';   // core: alias for './core
import Textbox from 'extensions/Textbox'; // extensions: alias for './extensions'

// Export all classes to use it in another project / package
module.exports = {
  Component,
  Textbox
};
```

**Webapp Module:**

```
// --- Webapp Module - entry.js (will transpile via babel to index.js)

import Components from 'components';

var welcome_text = new Components.Textbox();
welcome_text.set_text('Hello User!');
welcome_text.render('body');
```

So if I write `Components.` then I want to get a list of all exported classes from my 'components' module. Is that possible?

```
Components.Te  // show autocomplete list with all what starts with 'Te'

var tb = new Component.Textbox();
tb.myFuncti // show autocomplete for Textbox-class methods and properties
```

Maybe I export it in a wrong way or syntax. I thought maybe I need another 'babel' plugin which keeps the transpiled classes, properties and methods to recognize from the IDE.

For example in React. There I get a full list with everything:

```
import React from 'react';

React.Co // Shows me everything from React
```

*(It's not easy to describe all this in a short way, I hope it's not to hard to get in and understand what I mean :/ )*